# Want to call each card data in their modal PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to give extra data of my card in modal where I'm trying to access card id and their data in the modal of the same card.
but I tried the same PHP code into modal but it gave me data of every id in one modal just because I didn't specify the accurate id.

This is my card code:

```
<?php
 $postquery="SELECT * FROM card";
 $run=mysqli_query($db,$postquery); 
?>
   <section>
    <div class="container1">
      <?php 
        while($card=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
      ?>  
     <div class="container__card">
     <div class="container__card--content">
       <img src="../images/<?=getcardimagesinfo($db,$card['id'])?>" style="width:100%; 
        height:100px !important"/>
       <h3><?=$card['Name']?></h3>
       <h3><?=$card['id']?></h3>
       <button type="button" id="modalss" class="a modalss" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- 
        target="#exampleModal">Start</button>
     </div>
     </div>  
       <?PHP
            } 
       ?>
  </div>
```

This one is my modal

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria- 
 hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">  
        <h5 class="modal-title text-light" id="exampleModalLabel">Card full Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-id data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria- 
         label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:white;"> 
      <?PHP 
        while($card=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
      ?>  
      <h6>Description: <?=$card['Description']?></h6>
      <h6>Hint: <?=$card['hints']?></h6>
      <?php
       }
      ?>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your buttons to open the modal all have the same ID (`id="modalss"`). This is invalid HTML. Each ID must be unique. Also, your question is not clear. Please simplify your question to state the problem you are having.

Comment: If you are not a native speaker (as I am not a native speaker either), please try to write short sentences, which describe your problem much easier. For example:


- I retrieve cards info a database table and generate a list of these cards.
- On each card there is a button. 
- When I click any button, a modal is opened.
- I want to show some of the card info in the modal, on which the button was clicked.

Otherwise we have 2 problems at the same time: To understand your text, to understand your code.

Comment: Yes, there is 5 columns in my database table where I want to keep "id", and "name" into cards but every card have a modal that will share cards description and hint. So the question is how can I call the data of the same card in my modal as I'm clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all render all of your cards:**

```
<?php

$postquery="SELECT * FROM card";
$run=mysqli_query($db,$postquery);


$allCards = [];
while($card=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
{
    $allCards[] = $card;
}
?>
<section>
    <div class="container1">
        <?php
        foreach($allCards as $card){
            $cardId = $card['id'];
            $img = getcardimagesinfo($db,$cardId);
        ?>
            <div class="container__card">
                <div class="container__card--content">
                    <img src="../images/<?=$img?>" style="width:100%; height:100px !important" alt="Image of card"/>
                    <h3><?=$card['Name']?></h3>
                    <h3><?=$card['id']?></h3>
                    <button id="card-<?=$cardId?>" type="button" class="a modalss"
                        onclick="updateModalContent(this)"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                        Start
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Then embed your modal at the bottom of your page content.**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-light" id="exampleModalLabel">Card full Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-id data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-
         label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:white;">
        <h6>Description: <span id="modal-card-description"></span></h6>
        <h6>Hint: <span id="modal-card-hint"></span></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Finally add JavaScript section at the bottom to handle updating data in the modal window:**

```
<script>
    // This contains all cards info as Json object in javascript when the page is loaded
    var allCards = <?php echo json_encode($allCards);?>;

    // Button click handler
    function updateModalContent(clickedButton)
    {
        let cardId = clickedButton.id.split("-")[1];
        let thisCardInfo = allCards[cardId];

        document.getElementById('modal-card-description').innerHTML = thisCardInfo.description;
        document.getElementById('modal-card-hints').innerHTML = thisCardInfo.hints;
        // and so on ....
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks you but as I said description and hints will also retrieve from the database so show me how do I call description and hints of the same card as we clicked.

Comment: @haxhaxer It is already done in my solution. You should read all parts carefully. At least the different öarts which I wrote. In the first part you read all cards from the DB and render all cards as html. The second part contains updated modal dialog. And finally in the third part you have the JavaScript variable "allCards", which contain all cards information. The JavaScript function updateModalContent() reads from that variable and actualizes the modal content with the clicked card information.

Comment: @haxhaxer If you have many hundred or thousand cards, you need to limit your SQL query result, so that only a subset of all cards are shown on the page. But this is an another logic. And not the part of this question here.

Comment: @haxhaxer Did you implement this code and tried to understand how it works?